# how to pass post parameter in Django rest swagger?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-swagger

I have integrated swagger with django rest framework, but the swagger docs does not create a input box to post data for post request.

I am using Function based views with decorator(@api_view)

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny, ))
@renderer_classes([OpenAPIRenderer, SwaggerUIRenderer])
def preferences(request,format=None):
    try:
             "logic starts here "
```

in urls.py i have added:

```
  schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='API')         
  path('', schema_view, name="schema_view"),
```

in settings.py :

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
'USE_SESSION_AUTH': False,
'JSON_EDITOR': True,
'api_version': '0.1',
'enabled_methods': [
    'GET',
    'POST',
],
'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
    "api_key": {
        "type": "apiKey",
        "name": "Authorization",
        "in": "header"
    },
},
```

}

But, when i open the api url i'm getting something like this (in image) where i'm unable to pass the parameters through post[image: screenshot of api hit url]

what can be the problem here?is there any other changes to be done ?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the `Try it Out` link, you should get an input to fill in the POST data

Comment: When I click the "Try it out" button all that shows up is "No parameters". No box to enter post data.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the class is imported from the generics API, example:

```
from rest_framework import generics

class Something (generics.GenericAPIView):

     serializer_class=SomeSerializer

     def post(self,request):
         pass
```